# Wordpress List all pages and children in separate ul

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to do this all weekend, I'm going round in circles now.

I want to list all pages and their children in separate ul's

The page setup is like this

```
    HOME        ABOUT         CONTACT
                Who we are    Where we are 
                What we do    How to find us
                How we do it
```

I want to output it like this

```
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Who we are</li>
      <li>What we do</li>
      <li>How we do it</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Where we are</li>
      <li>How to find us</li>
    </ul>
```

This code below will give me the top pages in separate ul's

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'parent' => 0,
      );
      $pages = get_pages($args);
      foreach($pages as $page){
        ?>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <?php 
                        echo $page->post_title;
                    ?>  
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
      }

    ?>
```

I'm now trying to add the child pages to the same ul

I'm thinking something like this but this gives me all the pages in each ul

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'parent' => 0,
      );
      $pages = get_pages($args);
      foreach($pages as $page){
        ?>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <?php 
                        echo $page->post_title;
                        wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&child_of'.$page->ID.'');
                    ?>  
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
      }

    ?>
```

Is there a way to say all children of this page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&child_of'.$page->ID.'');

you'r missing the "=" after "child_of"

```
wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&child_of='.$page->ID.'');
```

The nicer way to do this is to create a custom walker, but this is more complicated
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class

Comment: Thanks obi_mihai, best part of a day messing with this and I was missing a "="

Comment: Might have spoken too soon. The first echo echo $page->post_title; just gives me text of the page but I need that to be a link as well

Comment: for the link you'll need to use get_permalink( $page->ID ); and put it in <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->page_title; ?></a>